# Finding the difference between two centers after rotation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm making a royo canvas editor but with HTML, everything is perfect but I have a trigonometry problem that I can't get out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErKNo.png

I break it 10deg to the right or left and then increase the height to 302px. It then moves to the opposite side when it should remain in the same position.

The problem is that I have to calculate the difference between the rotated and increased center from the unrotated center to get the difference and subtract it to get the same location.

I currently use a formula to do just the opposite, which is to get X2, Y2 and X1, Y1 having the rotation and the center point.

```
const center = { x: layer.size.width / 2, y: layer.size.height / 2 };
const rotate = this.getAbsoluteRotation(layer) * Math.PI / 180;

return {
      x: center.x - center.x * Math.abs(Math.cos(rotate)) - center.y * Math.abs(Math.sin(rotate)),
      y: center.y - center.x * Math.abs(Math.sin(rotate)) - center.y * Math.abs(Math.cos(rotate))
};
```

I understand that I need the reverse of this formula.

Thank you ;)